# I am using a non-apple wireless keyboard that gets keep disconnecting

Tags: keyboard, mac, bluetooth, sonoma

I am using a non-apple keyboard that gets keep disconnecting however the keyboard is made for mac use only. The keyboards gets is connected initially after logging in through a wired keyboard and after not using it for about 3-4 mins it gets disconnected, to connect it again I press a random key an then I get this [image: connection request pop up]

however it gets connected but its very annoying.I was using MacOS Ventura in that the connection stayed a bit longer however after updating to MacOS SONOMA on my Mac Mini M2 the connection last for a much shorter time.

So please help me how to make it connect permanently and please tell if it is possible to connect it on password screen also?

Thanks !!

Comment: Making it connect permanently without all those disconnect/reconnect issues might best be dealt with with tech support from the keyboard manufacturer. Also maybe they have a firmware update that fixes this. Have you checked?

Comment: It's not a very high end device so maybe i will have to manage it that way
but thanks for your reply sir!